# C++ Error invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const std::chrono::year_month_day')

Tags: c++, c++20, clion, cout, c++-chrono

can you help me resolve this error

> invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'const std::chrono::year_month_day')

I compile the source code with
CLion 2023.3.2
C++ 20
Apple Silicon M1
clang++ version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.2.0
Thread model: posix

Source code

Colonna.h

```
#ifndef SUPERE_COLONNA_H
#define SUPERE_COLONNA_H

#include <chrono>

namespace colonna {

    class Colonna {
    public:
        Colonna(const std::chrono::year_month_day &dataC);

        const std::chrono::year_month_day &getData() const;

        void setData(const std::chrono::year_month_day &dataC);

    private:
        // Data
        std::chrono::year_month_day dataC;
    };

} // colonna

#endif //SUPERE_COLONNA_H
```

Colonna.cpp

```
#include "Colonna.h"

namespace colonna {

    Colonna::Colonna(const std::chrono::year_month_day &dataC) : dataC(dataC) {}

    const std::chrono::year_month_day &Colonna::getData() const {
        return dataC;
    }

    void Colonna::setData(const std::chrono::year_month_day &dataC) {
        Colonna::dataC = dataC;
    }


} // colonna
```

main.cpp

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include "Colonna.h"

using namespace colonna;
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {

    Colonna colonna ({month(1)/day(12)/year(2024)});
    std::cout << colonna.getData() << '\n';
}
```

Thank you all

I ran the tests with the IDE and with the following commands

clang++ --std=c++20 main.cpp
clang++ --std=gnu++20 main.cpp

Comment: What makes you think you can print a `std::chrono::year_month_day`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Probably this: [`std::chrono::operator<<(std::chrono::year_month_day)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/operator_ltlt)

Comment: Note that `Apple clang version 15.0.0` has nothing to do with (upstream) clang 15. Apple's toolchain has its version information patched to match Xcode (in this case Xcode 15) and it's borderline impossible to figure out what public clang version that corresponds to, but usually they lag behind by well over a year.

Comment: @ScottHunter I wanted to print the date entered, and process a series of database calls adding one day at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [clang version string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-_12.x_(since_Free_On-Device_Development)) `clang-1500.1.0.2.5` maps to LLVM version 16.0.0.

Unfortunately [`std::chrono::operator<<(std::chrono::year_month_day)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/operator_ltlt) wasn't added to clang's libc++ until LLVM 17 as can be seen in this [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9cj3T3e87).